# Calculate second between my data and current data

Tags: java, android, date, time

How can i calcutate the second that are between a currentTime and another date?

```
long time = myData - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get current. Then use `System.currentTimeMillis()` again on the time of offset. Then use the latest one and subtract the first one.

[SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29) returns time since bootup. not a speific time.

Comment: So i can do long time = object.getData - System.currentTimeMillis() ??

Comment: if  object.getData  returns the time in milliseconds of the date you want. yes.

Comment: No, it return gregorian calendar. What thing i change?

Comment: Please make your question more clear. What is object.getData, what are your output atm?

Comment: Ok sorry. I have an object composed by some variable and a gregorian calendar, so when i do getData() it return for example 4-10-2013. So i must calculate the millisecond that are between that data and the currentTime.

Comment: Ok in this case. get your gregorian calendar object as `calendar`. then use `calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND))` , to get the milliseconds of that moment. then use `TheMilliSecYouJustGot-System.currentTimeMillis() ` to get the difference.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using the modern API:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // An arbitrary GregorianCalendar for demo - you will get it from object.getData
        GregorianCalendar gcal = GregorianCalendar
                .from(ZonedDateTime.of(2021, 5, 2, 10, 20, 30, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault()));

        ZonedDateTime start = gcal.toZonedDateTime();
        ZonedDateTime current = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(start, current);

        System.out.println(seconds);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
353263
```

**Note:** In the code given above, I have used  `ZoneId.systemDefault()` which returns the  `ZoneId` of your JVM. Replace it with the applicable `ZoneId` e.g. `ZoneId.of("Europe/London")`.

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

FYI, Joda-Time offers a `Seconds` class.

```
long secs = Seconds.between( new DateTime( myGregCal.getTime() ), DateTime.now() ).getSeconds();
```